# Which sites are running Site Satisfaction Survey?

Tags: support

Currently there is Site Satisfaction Survey running on Stack Overflow.

One of the question mentions other sites like Super User, Server Fault and DevOps.

Is this survey Stack Overflow specific or is the same (or similar) survey available for users of other mentioned sites?

If not, why?

---

There is related question asked on Stack Overflow Meta [What does “Should we add technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps to Stack Overflow?” mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392689/4267244)

Assuming that this particular survey question asks about merging all those sites I would also assume that users of those sites would also want to chime in with their opinions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently the Site Satisfaction Survey is only running on Stack Overflow. The link is shown to a randomly sampled set of users (both anonymous and logged in).

Comment: Thanks! There is related question on SO Meta [What does “Should we add technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps to Stack Overflow?” mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392689/4267244) that also begs an official answer.

Comment: Additionally, if the above question is some suggestion to merge sites (at least that is how I am reading it), why is this survey running only on SO and not on related sites?

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile that other question will get it's own answer in its own time. No need to copy it here. It is running only on SO because at the moment we do not currently have the staff bandwidth to be able to handle results coming from the survey running on multiple sites simultaneously. We hope to expand on this in the future when we are able to.