# Is there such a thing as an SE angst-o-meter? Some attempt to quantify on a site-by-site basis?

Tags: discussion, se-quality-project

The (currently unanswered) meta question [Were plans made for metrics associated with the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286348/303080) ends:

> Is there a way to try to identify the greatest sources of user satisfaction, and the greatest sources of *user angst*?
>
> Maybe it is ultimately impossible, but maybe not!

I know that pure angst is intangible but I also know that in the last years much progress has been made to improve things by addressing issues relating to user experience that could be quantified in some way, e.g. *What do you like least about...*"

In my personal experience I feel that there are some sites where contention or frustration is actively and quickly addressed, and others where things that can't be validly flagged generally aren't, and anecdotal experience suggests a positive correlation with question rate; faster Q rate can prohibit nuanced interpretations, less overt things requite too much time to investigate.

But one user can't make anything like a statistical analysis.

1. Are there tools that attempt to measure angst on a per-site basis?
2. Are there places where I can see some of the results? For example can I see how my personal experience compares to some metrics?

Comment: Similar questions and answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342779/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342832/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341721/282094 a little bit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351218/282094

Comment: @Rob yes, "Not that I'm aware of" is the answer to the ten month old [Is there any user satisfaction data for other SE sites than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342832/303080) If that's still the case, then *that's the answer.* But if there's something more that can address my question specifically, maybe leave this open a while to find out?

Comment: uhoh: "... I know that pure angst is intangible ...", yes difficult to automagically quantify, but maybe there's a SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236740/bounties-cancelled-by-moderators  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1229412/users-with-10-or-more-meta-posts-with-score-of-2-or-more-convention-badge  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1196964/1-reputation-users-with-a-meta-posts-with-more-than-5-votes-active-in-last-6-mon --- It depends on *what* you define as 'happy' and if it can be quantified by data. --- The CMs may answer

Comment: Down votes are great but I'm having trouble understanding what specifically the down votes indicate; is it "we shouldn't quantify" or "it shouldn't be broken down on a site-by-site basis"? I can't interpret what they hope to communicate.

Comment: You have no close votes, so that's a plus (or not). As for the DVs -  The [Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) reason, and a bit of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328160/282094) and [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342779/282094).

Comment: @Rob Might [The Loop: A community health indicator](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/12/18/the-loop-a-community-health-indicator/) now be a possible answer to my question? It certainly sounds like it might be to me, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know for sure. My "Angst-o-Meter" would be a community health indicator, no?

Comment: uhoh - There was a bit of discussion in "The Tavern" chat room, **how** does one accurately and reliably measure the 'health of the community' - many people don't even visit the site's metas, so how to go there and measure ... --- As you mentioned in your question: "... pure angst is intangible ...". --- So, your answer to the new question in [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354366/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-se-angst-o-meter-some-attempt-to-quantify-on-a-site?noredirect=1#comment1196766_354366) is "no, at best it's a year or more away; and that's optimistic".

Answer (score 9):

Not as far as any of us mods know. And *if* we had one, it would have exploded last year.

It's also worth considering the trajectory the company took - (and this is probably a good [inflection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343802/what-data-about-meta-has-eluded-stack-exchange-until-recently/343839#343839) point to look at, and contrast it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/what-about-the-community-is-toxic-to-new-users)).

Angst on its own feels like a meaningless measurable metric.

We can rather realise these are squishy human problems and try to listen to and understand the *causes* of angst and try to use statistics to identify what these are and understanding/dealing with *the communities in question* to mitigate these.

What I would love to know however are

- what are the biggest barriers of entry for a new user on my site?
- What are the barriers of entry for a user from going from a 'casual' user to a 'regular user' to a 'dedicated or core' user?
- If I am losing users from these groups, why?
- What are my regular and core users main concerns?

And of course I think the above gives a great example of how the *interpretation* of statistics, and *how* best to deal with it, vary and matter.

On meta for example, I think the powers that be are *entirely* aware of what causes angst, and some of this might be addressed, some might not. These would be *entirely* different from what makes someone angsty on, say, Super User.

And frankly four years on, and with the changes that have happened - I feel the SE quality project could use a fresh start on the road map.

Comment: What is the "SE quality project"? There is [a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/se-quality-project/info) for it, but what is story/history of it? E.g., is it an actual project that was launched/announced at some specific point in time?

Comment: I would guess [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project). It's just one of those great ideas worth revisiting cause it was kinda left by the way side for some reason.

Comment: There is (was?) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314563/303080). I'm not sure if "site-by-site" or "available" apply and there are many other behaviors besides that that can elevate angst. I guess moderators are the primary angst-o-meters if such a thing can exist, and if they choose to do so (measure our squishy human problems quantitatively). It sounds hard.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Are there tools that attempt to measure angst on a per-site basis?

I heavily doubt so. At least such tools need to have some datapoints, e.g.:

- How many users ask once and never (define a certain time period) come back to ask another question
- How quickly questions are deleted by users after receiving a single DV
- etc. I dunno

It's probably not so easy to draw out these statistics, with what's in the database.

> 2. Are there places where I can see some of the results? For example can I see how my personal experience compares to some metrics?

- Well, were you surveyed regarding your *"expierience of acceptance"*? If not, I am afraid there's nothing to go and see.